# Laravel Eloquent Only Get One Row

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I want to show id from order table where user id is the same as currently login user id, then later used to show orders have been made by the user

```
$orderId = Order::select('id')->firstWhere('user_id', auth()->id())->id;

$orders = SubOrder::where('order_id', $orderId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

it works but it only shows the first record, after some digging later I found out that the problem is on the $orderId, it only shows the first record. but I want it to be all the records. if I change the id to get(), it shows nothing since it give the result like "id = 1" instead of the number only. also have tried to change the firstWhere into where and got error like "Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance."
please help, thanks

Comment: what do you want here actually?? get all the orders with the sub orders for the currently logged in user??

Comment: suborder is just the name, actually it has the same records as the order, but more detailed. the main problem is the $orderId only shows the first record not all the record id

Comment: SubOrder will return as many rows that has the order_id $orderId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use the other `Orders` associated with the `User` soon after you get the first `Order`, return all the relevant `Orders` and then just grab the first one when you need it.

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();

$firstOrder = $orders->first();

$subOrders = SubOrder::whereIn('order_id', $orders->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Alternatively, you could use a `subOrders` relationship defined on your `Order` model.

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function subOrders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubOrder::class);
    }
}
```

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();

$firstOrder = $orders->first();

$firstOrderSubOrders = $firstOrder->subOrders;
```

If you're confident you're going to be working with `SubOrder` records, you can use eager loading on your `Order` to improve performance.

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->with('subOrders')
    ->get();

$firstOrder = $orders->first();

$firstOrderSubOrders = $firstOrder->subOrders;
```

Comment: @Binz Good stuff. I have added some alternative methods for reference.

Answer (score 0):

first() will return the first id queried and stop execution.

```
$firstOrder = $orders->first();
```